# Push notifications for phonegap app w/Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, cordova

I have a simple app that gets the current list of school closings for a specific area and displays the results in my app. I'd like to be able to set a school as a "favorite" and then, if the school is closed, a push notification would be displayed saying something like "Your school is closed!" I was contemplating on how to do this, and I thought simple jQuery could work.

1. The user would set a favorite school with an exact name.
2. jQuery would search all the closings in a certain body element (example, all  elements) and if the name was found from step 1, it would send the notification

Does anyone have any other ideas on how to do this, and if I can invoke the notification with Javascript?

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you use UrbanAirship to provide your push notifications. For an small amount of notifications (under 2000 a month I think) it is free.

https://support.urbanairship.com/customer/portal/articles/66970-implementing-with-phonegap

Comment: Thanks for the link, I'll check it out. How would this tie into the finding if the school is closed though?